# CCParticleSnow not looping/repeating.

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

I wrote this code.

```
 CCSpriteFrame *starParticleFrame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:spriteName];
            CCParticleSnow *emitter = [[CCParticleSnow alloc] initWithTotalParticles:8];

            [emitter setTexture:[starParticleFrame texture] withRect:[starParticleFrame rect]];
            emitter.position = ADJUST_XY(theScreenSize.width/2, 3*theScreenSize.height/4);
            emitter.scale = HD_PIXELS(1.5);

            emitter.speed = 20 + arc4random() %20;
            [emitter setDuration:kCCParticleDurationInfinity];

            //[emitter setGravity:CGPointMake(0, -150)];
            [self addChild: emitter z:-1];
```

It works. But problem is it just fire up the snow once, and not continuous. (in this case, just 8 particles came out and that's it).

However, if I exchange the 2nd line of code into

```
CCParticleSnow *emitter = [CCParticleSnow node];
```

then the particle system able to loop continuously. I read the docs and googled about this
but to no avail. The last try was to put that duration to kCCParticleDurationInfinity. But still not working.

Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You limit the emitter to 8 particles. It will only spawn new particles after the initial 8 are gone.

Comment: Ok make sense. I guess I misunderstood "initWithTotalParticle". Ended up using [CCParticleSnow node] and then emitter.emissionRate=5; to get what I desire. Thanks, again, Steffen. :)